# passing parameter for a function within a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to pass variable named 'count ' to a  function named 'myfunction()' and trying to print the count value, but the below code is not working.
can anyone please help me ?

```
     function display(count, name)
     {
     for(i=0;i<count;i++)  
       {
         var btn = document.createElement("button");
         btn.style.width = "80px";
         btn.innerText = name[i];
         btn.onclick =myfuncton(count)
        {
            alert(count);
        }
    }
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does _console_ say ?

Comment: @ rayon it displays button , but onclick is not working

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/sanvi4/uscuhzyr/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/erqejnmg/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of closures here.

Here is what you could do.

```
btn.onclick = (function(count) {
    return function() {
      alert(count);
    }
  })(count);
```

More about [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on MDN